# Embed video HTML5 UIActivityViewController IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, video, uiactivityviewcontroller

Is it possible to embed a video using HTML5 in UIActivityViewController. The code I am using below generates a blank email body when sharing via email.

```
NSString * shareMessage = @"<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\"></head><body><video controls=\"\" autoplay=\"\" name=\"media\"><source src=\"https://myurl.com/video_test.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video></body></html>";    

NSArray * activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           shareMessage,
                           nil];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                                    applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The reason why I would like to use HTML and stream the video rather than embedding the video locally from a file, is so that it can play embedded in the email body and not appear as a file attachment.

Any ideas if what I am trying to do is possible? Can't find any examples out there...

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it is possible, although you need to create a new class for the UIActivityViewController. I had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203908/how-to-add-different-text-to-uiactivityviewcontroller-objects) a long time ago and this [link](http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/2012/10/objective-c-custom-uiactivityviewcontroller-icons-text/) was the key to my solution.

I used a new class and defined all the different messages for the UIActivityViewController.

**1. Create UIActivityItemProvider Class**

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CustomActivityClass : UIActivityItemProvider <UIActivityItemSource>
@end
```

.m

```
#import "CustomActivityClass.h"

@implementation CustomActivityClass


- (id) activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
          itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
    if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter] )
        return @"text";
    if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook] )
        return @"text";
    if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage] )
        return @"text";
    if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail] )
        return @"<html><body> \n"
        "<h1 style=\"font:15px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif\"> \n"
        "text \n"
        "<b> \n"
        "bold text \n"
        "</b> \n"
        "</h1> \n"
        "<p style=\"font:13px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif\"> \n"
        "some text\n"
        "</p> \n"
        "</body></html>";

    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
    NSLog(@"%@", activityType);
    return [super activityViewController:activityViewController itemForActivityType:activityType];

    return nil;
}
- (id) activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController { return @""; }



@end
```

That is literally all you need. Just replace my html example with your html video and it should probably work fine.

Here is the additional code to initialize the Controller with your button/action:

```
CustomActivityClass *ActivityProvider = [[CustomActivityClass alloc] init];

        NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: ActivityProvider,nil];


        UIActivityViewController *ActivityView =
        [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items
                                          applicationActivities:nil];
```

Have a good one and feel free to comment questions!

Cheers

Comment: This example works great, only thing is that it doesn't show how to put a video using html in the email body. It would be great if you can show this html working for a local video file or a video file hosted on a server like this one: http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5

Comment: @mikemeli check out this post. It might help you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926248/html5-video-not-playing-in-native-ios-email-client-2015

Answer (score 0):

Well the `<embed src="...">` will insert your video and your HTML ends up less cluttered, and the

`<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>`

tag is your best bet as you just puts up your video. Now, of course that is, when you link it to your file.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Comment: I tried the video tag, but the composed email says "Your browser does not support the video tag". Any ideas?